# Entity Framework connection string connecting to file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

Is there a way to build Entity Framework connection string
to connect to a file-Database in a standalone c# application?

Comment: What do you mean by "file-database"? Maybe you can checkout Biggy - A File-based Document Store for .NET https://github.com/robconery/biggy

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
<add name="ConnectionName"
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DatabaseName.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: add @ before connection string connectionString=@""

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [Sql Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx), which can be embedded directly into your application.

Quote from the page:

> Do you need to embed SQL Server Express into an application? LocalDB
>   is a lightweight version of Express that has all its programmability
>   features yet runs in user mode and has a fast, zero-configuration
>   installation. (...) LocalDB runs in-process with applications and not as a service.

You can download the installer from that same page.